Unable to parse non-ASCII characters from exported Instagram chat log
I requested a data download from Instagram and I chose the JSON format. However, when I got the file and unzipped it, every non-ASCII character was represented as a Unicode escape sequence. E.g.:
"sender_name": "Le\u00c3\u00b3 Tak\u00c3\u00a1cs"

The correct text would be: "sender_name": "Leó Takács"
I tried parsing the JSON file with Python and correcting the errors somehow, but instead of getting "ó" for "\u00c3\u00b3", I got Ã³. It seems like, every way I tried, it always returned the characters individually decoded. The same thing happened with emojies too, so hardcoding every problematic character to be replaced would be a bit of a headache. I would prefer a solution that is doable programatically, but at this point any idea including 3rd party software plays.

A similar problem was reported several years ago regarding the same bad JSON encoding in Facebook Messenger data. And Facebook owns Instagram. Coincidence?

It would appear that Each UTF-8 byte is being interpreted as a Unicode character, or in other words UTF-8 being interpreted as Latin 1 encoded text.
data = '"sender_name": "Le\u00c3\u00b3 Tak\u00c3\u00a1cs"'
cleaned = data.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
print(cleaned)
# "sender_name": "Leó Takács"

i.e. "Le\u00c3\u00b3 Tak\u00c3\u00a1cs" should have been b'"Le\xc3\xb3 Tak\xc3\xa1cs"'.

I'm really thankful for your answer! I was reading the contents in from a file, and your solution was using a hardcoded string. Mine was printing out the Unicode escape sequences literally and your's was printing them out with substitusions in place. It took me a while to figure out, but I converted my file to json, dumped it to a string with ensure_ascii=False and then encoded that string with your method, and after hours of trial and error, it finally works! So thank you again, and I hope it helps others parsing Instagram exports.
